# MVC DropDownListFor how to add RouteLink

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.1

Hi sorry for asking such an easy question but I'm scratching my head all day today and cannot figure this out. I found lots of similar questions but non of them resolve my problem.

I had a page with list of products and few buttons to filter products by category. Because number of products has increased I decided to change them to drop down box.

So I have drop down box which populates categories:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCategoryId, Model.CategoryItems, new { id = "changeCategory" })
```

and javascript which fires on change event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#changeCategory").change(function () {
        var selectedCategory = $(this).text();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("List", "Deal")',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { category: selectedCategory },
            cache: false,
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This doesn't work. My previous routing works with the code below:

```
@foreach (var link in Model) {
    @Html.RouteLink(link, new {
        controller = "Deal", 
        action = "List",
        category = link,
        page = 1
    }, new {
    @class = "btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg"
    })
}
```

UPDATE:

I have changed the jQuery code to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#changeCategory").change(function () {
        var selectedCategory = $("#changeCategory option:selected").text();
        $.ajax({
            url: selectedCategory,
            type: 'POST',
            cache: true,
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

and the link looks correct now but the website doesn't reload. When I watch this in the Chrome Developer Tool in Network section the link appear there and when I click it it does open correct page.

Why it doesn't do that on website?

UPDATE 2

My Controller

```
public ViewResult List(string category, int page = 1)
    {
        DealsListViewModel model = new DealsListViewModel
        {
            Deals = repository.Deals
            .Where(p => category == null || p.Category == category)
            .OrderBy(p => p.DealID)
            .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
            .Take(PageSize),
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalItems = repository.Deals.Count()
            },
            CurrentCategory = category
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

Any help is appriciated

Comment: AJAX calls stay on the same page. Are you trying to redirect to another page or are you trying to load some data into the current page?. Please post you `List()` method for the `Deal` controller

Comment: I have updated the question. Preferably I would like to update data on this page, but if it is not possible I will use your answer to redirect the page. Many thanks

Comment: You can update the data on he current pages by returning a partial view. I'll update answer shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you want to redirect to the `List` method of `DealController` and pass the text of the selected option. If so then

```
$("#changeCategory").change(function () {
  window.location.href = '@Url.Action("List", "Deal")' + '/' + $(this).find('option:selected').text();
});
```

assuming your action method is something like

```
public ActionResult(string someValue)
```

AJAX calls stay on the same page and do not redirect to another page.
And out of curiosity, why override the default `id` (and not just use `$("#SelectedCategoryId").change(...`)?

**Edit**

If you want to return some html to include on the page, return a partial view and update the  page html in the AJAX success function

Controller

```
public PartialViewResult List(string category, int page = 1)
{
  DealsListViewModel model = new DealsListViewModel ....
  ....
  return PartialView(model)
}
```

Script (assumes you have an element with `id="results" where you want to render the returned html)

```
$("#changeCategory").change(function () {
  var url = '@Url.Action("List", "Deal")';
  var category = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
  var page = ? // if you want to pass this as well
  $.get(url, { category: category, page: page }, function(data) {
    $('#results').html(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, please look on the comment below the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your ajax call:

```
type: 'POST'
```